# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor' Error in Robot framework for Stored Procedure call

Tags: python, python-2.7, robotframework

I am working on updating database records using Stored procedure in Robot framework.

I am referring https://franz-see.github.io/Robotframework-Database-Library/api/1.0.1/DatabaseLibrary.html#Call%20Stored%20Procedure.

After executing the script I get the following error

**AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor'**

I have no clue why I get this error, I searched on various stackoverflow threads but couldn't figure out how to resolve this. Could you please help?

Here is my code sample

```
*** Settings ***
Suite Setup       Connect To Database Using Custom Params    ibm_db_dbi     ${db_connection}
Suite Teardown    Disconnect From Database
Library           DatabaseLibrary
Library           OperatingSystem  
Resource          ../resources/variables/variables.txt


*** Test Cases ***


Test updatedb storedprocedure
    @{ParamList} =    Create List     3    <Key><empid>1234</empid></Key>    10.5
    @{QueryResults} =    Call Stored Procedure       ${SPName}       ${ParamList}
    Log to console  ${QueryResults}
```

Comment: Your provided code does not seem to be python. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I would like to be able to paste your code into IDLE and run it without having to research it and download third-party code.

Comment: Did you connected to database prior executing keyword? :)

Comment: yes i have connected to database i still it fails

Comment: Have you tried a simple query?

Comment: I tried to run stored procedure in DB2 it works there however from robot framework it doesn't work

Comment: Did you try to run simple query, some select statement?

Comment: no i didn't try other queries